# org-mode and bibtex latex export problem

Tags: org-mode, org-export, bibtex

I followed [this](http://chenla.org/2016/08/07/capturing-bibtext-entries-with-org-bibtex-mode-google-scholar.html) and can grab stuff (with Google Scholar) and put it in my `ref.org`, as described. However when I create a `testbibtex.org` with this lone line:

```
\bibliography{ref}
```

all I get with Latex export is the word "Contents." I've copied the contents of `ref.org` to `ref.bib`, entries such as this:

```
@book{burton2006elementary,
  title={Elementary number theory},
  author={Burton, David M},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Tata McGraw-Hill Education}
}
```

but nothing of this is included in the Latex export. So, yeah, I really need a beginner's tutorial in this whole process.

Comment: What are you expecting to see? You've included a reference to your bibliography file, but you didn't actually cite anything. Given an effectively empty input file, the exported file will be empty too!

Comment: I get "link is unreachable" when clicking your link.

Answer (score 4):

I'm doing latex bibliography exports in Org9 with a regular bibtex file (literature.bib).  At the location where I want the references to appear in the result, I put

`#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: /HOME/uidg1626/literature apalike`

into my org file or sub-header (for sub-tree export). Citing is done with org links e.g. `[[cite:key_of_bibtex_entry]]`.

Before the above can work the org pdf compiling process hast to be configured (e.g. in init.el) to include a bibtex run:

```lisp
(require 'ox-bibtex)
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
      '("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "bibtex %b"
        "pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
```

I got it from here: http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/anno-bib-template-worg.html#sec-5 which is working for my tex-live system.

Comment: Not working. Was that tutorial I was referring to not correct? As I say, I need to know the latest, accurate init details. I'm sure my problem lies in my init salad.

Comment: @147pm: I'm sorry I forgot to mention the `org-latex-pdf-process` (updated my answer accordingly).

Comment: This worked for me thank you so much - but I did have to remove the `(require 'ox-bibtex)` for some reason